# What's the safest way to have a blog in Laravel (Authentication)

Tags: php, laravel, security, blogs

I've made blogs with Laravel in the past, however I never actually published them. I want to have a blog where the only authentication needed is for me, to post articles, and I'll have some sort of social authentication for people to comment.

Which is the safest way to do this? Laravel's super-simple `php artisan make:auth` springs to mind, however I'm not really too sure how safe it is. The other thing I was thinking of was just allowing the user to post things if their IP address is my public IP address, however I really don't know how easily that could be cracked.

Any help/solutions much appreciated.

Comment: Laravel's Authentication is perfectly safe on its own. If you want a little extra validation, you can certainly add your own Middleware to validate a whitelist of IP addresses.

Comment: Cool! Thanks very much